# Error message stating misplaced constructors for java

Tags: java, random, static-methods, instance-variables

So I reworked it some but now I am getting the additional error of "complete the whilestatement?

```java
/* This is a program in that can figure out a number chosen by a human user
*/
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuesser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean playAgain = false;

        do {
            playOneGame();
            playAgain = shouldPlayAgain();
        } while (playAgain);
    }

    public static void playOneGame() {
        int continueGuessing = 0;
        int guess = 50;
        int low = 1;
        int high = 100; 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char response;  

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100.\n");
        do {
            guess = getMidpoint (low, high);
            response = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);
            if (response == 'h') {
                high = guess;
                continueGuessing = 1;
            } else if (response == 'l') {
                low = guess;
                continueGuessing = 0;
            }
            while(response != 'h' && response != 'l')
        }
    }

    /*get midpoint method       
    */
    public static int getMidpoint(int high, int low);
        int range = high- low;
        Random generator = new Random();

        if (range >0){
            int midpoint = generator.nextInt(range) + low +1;
            return midpoint;
        } else
            return guess;

    public static char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        char response;

        do {
            System.out.println("Is it " + guess + "? (h/l/c): ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            response = input.charAt(0);
        } while (response != 'h' && response != 'l' && response != 'c');
        return response;
    }

    static boolean shouldPlayAgain() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        String input;
        char response;

        do {
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (y/n); ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            response = input.charAt(0);
        } while (response != 'y' && response != 'n')

        if (response == 'y') {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So i am to create a program in that can figure out a number chosen by a human user. The human user will think of a number between 1 and 100. The program will make guesses and the user will tell the program to guess higher or lower.

A sample run of the program might look like this:

```
  Guess a number between 1 and 100.
  Is it 50?  (h/l/c): h
  Is it 75?  (h/l/c): h
  Is it 87?  (h/l/c): l  
  Is it 81?  (h/l/c): c
  Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): y
  Guess a number between 1 and 100.
  Is it 50?  (h/l/c): l
  Is it 25?  (h/l/c): h
  Is it 37?  (h/l/c): c
  Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): n
```

What I have attempted thus far is giving me many errors:

```java
 /* This is a program in that can figure out a number chosen by a human user
 */
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuesser {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean playAgain = false;
    do{
        playOneGame();
        playAgain = shouldPlayAgain();
    }while (playAgain);
}
/*get midpoint method       
 */

public static void playOneGame() {
    private int continueGuessing = 0;
    private int guess = 50,
                low = 1,
                high = 100; 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char    response;   
    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100.\n");
    do{
        guess = getMidpoint(low, high, guess);
        response = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);

        if (response == 'h') {
            high = guess;
            continueGuessing = 1;
        }

        else if (response == 'l'){
            low = guess;
            continueGuessing = 0;
        }
    }

    while (continueGuessing == 1);


 public static int getMidpoint;
    int range = high- low;
    Random generator = new Random();

    if (range >0){
        int midpoint = generator.nextInt(range) + low +1;
        return midpoint;
    }

    else
        return guess;


public static char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    char response;

    do {
        System.out.println("Is it " + guess + "? (h/l/c): ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        response = input.charAt(0);
    }
    while (response != 'h' && response != 'l' && response != 'c');

    return response;
}

static boolean shouldPlayAgain() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input;
    char response;

    do{
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (y/n); ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        response = input.charAt(0);
    }
    while (response != 'y' && response != 'n');

    if (response == 'y') {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You should precise what errors you get

Comment: Two of your methods are missing their closing bracket.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and use only spaces for indentation.  Or only tabs if you absolutely *must*.  Do not mix.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error, can't reference static with a non static, and not a declared variable

Comment: Also, I do apologize I am not sure how to go about properly formatting in this type of forum as I am completely new to all this.

Comment: Now I am getting an error "syntax error complete the while statement..

Comment: You still have a problem with a missing closing brace at the end of the `getMidpoint()` method.  You are also missing the semicolon (`;`) at the end of two of your `do { ... } while();` constructs.

Comment: You will find it easier to avoid these kinds of basic syntactic mistakes if you discipline yourself to (1) always introduce parentheses, brackets, and braces in matching pairs (before you add whatever goes between), write loop control structures before filling in loop bodies, and (3) maintain consistent indentation as you write your code.  Also, choose an editor that helps you with this sort of thing.  IDEs typically provide such editors, but you can get them as standalone products, too.

Comment: Actually, you are missing both closing *and* the opening brace of `getMidpoint()`.

Answer (score 1):

Java expects do-while statements to look like this:

```
do {
    ... statements
}
while (some test);
```

which is what you have in multiple spots. But in one place, here:

```
   do {
        guess = getMidpoint (low, high);
        response = getUserResponseToGuess(guess);
        if (response == 'h') {
            high = guess;
            continueGuessing = 1;
        } else if (response == 'l') {
            low = guess;
            continueGuessing = 0;
        }
        while(response != 'h' && response != 'l')
    } // <-- move this up to above the while
```

the closing brace is in the wrong spot, it needs to precede the while.

Of course getMidpoint() needs braces around it too, and an argument list. `public static int getMidpoint;` is the syntax you'd use for a class variable (which can't be declared within a method).

```
// added arguments, opening brace
public static int getMidpoint(int low, int high, int guess) { 
    int range = high- low;
    Random generator = new Random();

    if (range >0){
        int midpoint = generator.nextInt(range) + low +1;
        return midpoint;
    }

    else
        return guess;
} // added closing brace here
```

My impression is this is stuff you already know, you just haven't formed the work habits you need in order to keep errors from creeping in. The comment advising you to format your code consistently and to introduce control structures in matching pairs is good advice. It will also help if you write code in small pieces that you can try out as you go, instead of typing everything in at once, because getting hit with all the errors at once can be overwhelming.